# Unexpected method call when run junit easymock test

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I want to test this method and its conditions.

```
public String getType(String body) {
    String type = getTypeCode(body, 1); //this
    if (null == type) {
        type = getTypeCode(body, 2); //this
    }
    return type;
}
```

So I've written a test

```
@Test
public void testTypeOldToNew() {
    Parser parser = createMock(Parser.class);
    expect(parser.getTypeCode(BODY_2, 1)).andReturn(null);
    expect(parser.getTypeCode(BODY_2, 2)).andReturn(CODE_TWO_MESSAGE);
    replay(parser);
    parser.getType(BODY_2);
    verify(parser);
}
```

But when I run it I've got an error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call Parser.getype("value"):
    Parser.getTypeCode("value", 1): expected: 1, actual: 0
    Parser.getTypeCode("value", 2): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mock the class you are testing. You are calling `parser.getType(BODY_2);` **on the mock**. And as you haven't defined anything for that method, nothing happens (and defining what should happen doesn't make sense, because then you would be testing the mocking framework).

You need to mock interactions of this class with other classes (or better: interfaces).

Comment: Oh! I get it. So basically I should operate with real object there?

Comment: Yes, you need to work with the real object here. I once saw a project where a developer had written a lot of tests that only tested his own mocking setup instead of any actual code...